# data-ng-show and array elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am seeing syntax error on the console console for the following block of code but it works the way I wanted. What is that Im missing?

```
<p class="light" data-ng-show="selectedAppType in ['A1','A2','A3','A4'].indexOf(selectedAppType) > -1">
    You chose <b>{{selectedAppName}}.</b><br/>
    Please choose an <b> {{selectedAppName}} </b>Type.
    <br/>
    <b>Please check console for the error</b>
  </p>

http://plnkr.co/edit/c6rLz77Rm11mynuA2qZg?p=preview
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
selectedAppType in ['A1','A2','A3','A4'].indexOf(selectedAppType) > -1
```

This doesn't make much sense. You're kind of trying to do the same check twice. I can't remember what the order of operations is, but this would be either trying to check if `selectedAppType` is in a certain integer (result of `indexOf`), or if `selectedAppType` is in the boolean (result of the `> -1` comparison).

Change it to either

```
selectedAppType in ['A1','A2','A3','A4']
```

or

```
['A1','A2','A3','A4'].indexOf(selectedAppType) > -1
```